# Is there a frecency-based cache eviction algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, caching

I'm investigating whether frecency (combination of frequency and recency) is a better cache eviction policy than LRU.

The only way I can think of doing this is keeping a list of cache pages by frequency (number of times accessed) and another list by recency (time last accessed) and another list by frecency (calculated from the other lists by adding the position of a page in both lists together).

Unfortunately keeping three lists takes up a bunch of memory, and worse, every time a page is accessed I have to update all three lists.

I was wondering if there's a best practice frecency algorithm to do the same thing with less memory and processing overhead.  I've googled for it but haven't found anything.

Comment: B-trees are a good idea, especially if you've got a vast number of pages that have similar prefixes. However, I think something simpler, like my original answer (but using dictionaries and Counters, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) is likely to be perfectly fine and involve more readable code.

Comment: [Hyperbolic policy](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc17/atc17-blankstein.pdf) is probably the closest match to your intent. You might tweak the cost function from freq / age to freq / reuse-distance.

Answer (score 4):

There are many eviction policies that try to capture and balance frequency and recency. I have implemented many of them in this [simulator](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Simulator) for evaluation with public traces. You might enjoy playing with it, especially if you have your own trace files to experiment with. When choosing a scheme for my caching library, I [summarized](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency) the results of my analysis and overall library [design](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html) ([slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NlDxyXsUG1qlVHMl4vsUUBQfAJ2c2NsFPNPr2qymIBs)).

[TinyLFU](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3149371) employs a frequency sketch to compactly and probabilistically estimate an items popularity. After a sample period, it ages all the counters by halving them. This way the heavy hitters (hottest items) are recorded without the item having to be present in the working set, allowing for a larger history of accesses to be retained. TinyLFU compares the frequency of a new arrival with the eviction policy's victim, keeping the item most likely to be reused. This is known as an admission policy.

Unfortunately TinyLFU may degrade in recency-biased workloads by rejecting prematurely. In that case, the item starts cold, is used in short successions, and then not touched again. By the time TinyLFU admits it, multiple misses occurred and it now pollutes the cache by adding no future value. A good example of this is a distributed build cache, where a developer's local cache handles all but the newest check-ins for incremental building. When a change is committed, a query storm of requests fetch the changes and quickly cease.

This can be mitigated by using a small admission window (LRU) prior to being filtered by TinyLFU. This way the item is only rejected after it has been inactive, as in becoming less recent. The ideal size of this window is workload dependent, unfortunately. Recent work has gone into making it adaptive to dynamically tune based on the workload's characteristics. Since that paper is under anonymous review for a conference, I can't discuss it publicly yet. However, I'd be happy to chat over email and provide it privately.

There are other approaches based on their own interesting insights. LIRS is the other most promising approach from my experiments and it is based on LRU lists with ghost entries. Random sampling approaches have also been getting popular due to their low memory requirements, simplicity, and easy to make concurrent. However, the sampling algorithms that I've tested have underperformed compared to the more advanced policies.

Answer (score 2):

One b-tree is enough. Here's what you will need:

1. `cache entry` structure containing `(cached_data, recency, frequency, frecency)`.
2. Any key-value store of `(cache key)` -> `(cache entry)`. This will be the backing store of the cache.
3. A b-tree of `frecency` -> `buckets of (cache entry)`.

On every cache miss, calculate initial frequency, recency and frecency, put into backing store and b-tree bucket.

On every cache hit, the algorithm will have the old recency and frequency, therefore it will be able to update them and calculate new frecency score. Then it will update the backing store with new scores. Then, using the old frecency it will locate the corresponding bucket in a b-tree, remove our element from the bucket and move it into a different bucket.

So cache-miss will cost you an extra b-tree insert ( O(log n) ). And cache-hit will cost you extra backing-store write, b-tree search + delete + insert ( O(log n) ).

If you want, you can remove the frequency, recency and frecency scores from the backing store and extract them to a separate in-memory hashtable or something. This decision depends on other constraints.

Comment: So on a cache hit in order to calculate the new frecency we'd have to read all cache entries?

Comment: No, why? Store frequency as a counter and recency as a timestamp. Then frecency is a function of two integers and you never need to do anything with other entries, just update the btree with new frecency.

Comment: You know, I think you're right - this might be a lot simpler than I've been making it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just a sketch of an idea, so forgive me if it's not quite suited to your situation!

What if you only maintain 1 frequency list whose values decay over time? This will be like frecency, as recent views will be more heavily weighted. You can then adjust the rate of decay until you're happy with the formula.

If you look at page frequency each day, you could update the previous values by multiplying them and then simply add the most recent frequency values to the decayed list.

e.g.

```
pages = ['page_1', 'page_2', 'page_3'] # ...etc.
frequency = [1, 3, 7] # ...etc.

def update(old_freq, new_freq):
    old_freq = [i * 0.5 for i in old_freq]
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(old_freq, new_freq)]
```

You could then save the frequency list and the page mapping list to a file.

Obviously you'd need a way of appending/removing pages to/from the mapping, but you get the general idea.

Comment: Decay is not exactly the same as using recency as a weight. If the value is extremely frequently used at business days but never used at weekends - it will get thrown away. While a good frecency algorithm would keep it seeing that the frequency is too large to just throw it away.

Comment: I can see this working - frequently accessed pages would have a higher value so it would take longer to decay, and more recently accessed pages would have a higher value.  I think my biggest worry is that the whole list would need to be updated constantly, so there's still a lot of processing overhead.

Comment: Things will only get thrown away if you want to throw them away. E.g. you could only update the model on weekdays and disregard weekends (if you wanted, however this is unnecessary). Two days worth of decay won't make something vanish - it will just make it smaller. On that topic though, I bet you could make my suggestion a lot more efficient by storing frecency (decaying frequency in this case) in a dictionary rather than two lists - this would make it easier to add/remove pages & you could remove pages that had too little frecency so that you don't store loads of numbers close to zero